# AutoComplete- Off Not working

Tags: javascript, android, html

I have a webiview in my android Activity. In that webview i am uploading a native html page. 
the HTML page contains input text field. I am trying to use autocomplete-off to make Off 
Suggestions. But Autocomplete -off not working in android .some suggestions are still 
there when i try to input some text.

Code i am trying is given below

```
<tr>
    <td style="position:absolute; top:5%;height:35px;width:100%;" >
        <input type="text" id="userName" placeholder = "User Name" autocomplete ="off" >
    </td>
</tr>
```

Comment: post your code please

Comment: realy!! where i want to see!!

Comment: <tr><td  style="position:absolute;top:5%;height:35px;width:100%;" ><input type="text" id="userName"  placeholder = "User Name" autocomplete ="off" ></td></tr>

Comment: If Govind Sir, You Have Solution Provide Me.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/29582380/4462191 duplicate question?

Answer (score 1):

your input element doesn't have the name attribute. thats why its not working.

```
<tr>
    <td style="position:absolute; top:5%;height:35px;width:100%;" >
        <input type="text" name="textbox1" id="userName" placeholder = "User Name" autocomplete ="off" >
    </td>
</tr>
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try:

```
WebView.getSettings().setSavePassword(false);
WebView.clearFormData();
```

Comment: Sir, I Think Your Code Will Enable autoComplete- Off Only On the PassWord Field , Not Username Field. I Have Many Fields In My HTML Page.

Answer (score 0):

I got you if you load HTML native page which you already created then open html page and change type of it it may be completed from java-Script. just remove it.

and if possible just post your android code here so I can take a look at it and tell you that if there is any error in android code.

```
<form name="form1" id="form1" method="post" autocomplete="off" action="........">

   Name: <input type="text" name="text1" /><br/>
   Address: <input type="text" name="text2" /><br/>
   Phone: <input type="text" name="text3" /><br/>
   Password: <input type="password" name="password" /><br/>
 <input type="Submit" name="Submit" value="Submit" />

</form>
```

Comment: Sir, I Have Not Handle It Through Android code. Just Trying Through HTML Tag i.e <input type ="text" autocomplete = "off"/>

Comment: try this code which I edited above,put autocomplated="off" in <form> tag

Answer (score 0):

Chrome does not support `autocomplete="off"` at the form level for some input fields.

There are 2 solutions to do so:

- In your form, if only two or three fields ignore `autocomplete="off"`, then use the field name itself as the autocomplete value. i.e. `autocomplete=<input field name>`

  ```html
  <form:input type="text" id="name" path="name" autocomplete="name"/>
  ```
- Instead of defining field name manually for each field, use a script for all text typed input at the loading of the page or after.

  ```
  if ($.browser.chrome) { 
      $(document).on('focus click tap', 'input', function() {
          $(this).attr("autocomplete", 'block');
      });
  } else {
      $(document).on('focus click tap', 'input', function() {
          $(this).attr("autocomplete", 'off');
      });
  }
  ```